# How To Provide A Class To Fields In A Django Template?

Tags: python, django

I was working a project on mine, in which I needed to provide a class to a field in form which is a input box, but don't know how to do so.

My Template:

```
{% extends 'diary/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Register{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}

{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href = "{% static 'users/register.css' %}">

    <div id="login-box">
        <div class="left-box">
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for non_field_error in form.non_field_errors %}
                        <p>{{ non_field_error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                                {{ field }}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <p>{{ error }}</p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" name="signup-button" class="signup-btn">
                </form>
        </div>
        <div class="right-box">
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

In this specific part:

```
{% for field in form %}
                {{ field }}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
```

I want to provide a class to {{ field }}.

I tried this:

```
{{ field(class="txtb") }}
```

This is how I use to provide a class in Flask, but in Django this didn't worked.

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

Comment: You should do that in the `Form` itself.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, it'll really help if you'll elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## django-widget-tweaks

I'm using [`django-widget-tweaks`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) module for set HTML attribute in templates.

#### installation

1. install module using `pip install django-widget-tweaks`
2. add to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'widget_tweaks',
    ...
]
```

3. `{% load widget_tweaks %}` in templates file

#### usage

in templates code:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
...

{% for field in form %}
    {% render_field field class="txtb" %}
    ...
```

in HTML, looks like this:

```
<input class="txtb" ... ...>
```

reference [django-widget-tweaks github page](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) for more information.

---

## manually

Detailed description is in [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html#using-custom-html-attributes)

forms.py:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    modelfield = forms.CharField(
        ...,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'txtb'
            }
        }
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ...
        fields = ...
```

---

And I have a lot of information about django to [simpleisbetterthancomplex.com](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/archive/)
`django-widget-tweaks` also learned [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/04/package-of-the-week-django-widget-tweaks.html)

Comment: Thanks! but I really hope that there is an inbuilt Django functionality that can do this.

Comment: @Heisenberg I've added content